# Merge Arquivos XLS (JAVA)

Tags: java

Tenho Varios arquivos .xls com 1 sheet cada, gostaria de fazer o merge de todas as sheet em um unico arquivo com varias Sheet.

Comment: Rodrigo, você já tem algo trabalhado? Caso não, recomendo ver a biblioteca POI: https://poi.apache.org/. O jeito mais facil de fazer é criar um documento novo e copiar todas as células da sheet para ele. Ao copiar tudo, crie uma nova aba e repita o procedimento com os demais arquivos.

Comment: EU tenho um codigo funcionando, porem está perdendo toda a formatação na hora de mergear as demais sheets(arquivos). Ainda mais quando tem charts que tenho muitos. 
Está complicado

Comment: Quando você faz o merge, ele gera outro xlsx ou um csv? Vi uma discussão sobre copiar toda a sheet, incluindo formatação: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33749323/how-to-copy-xlsx-complete-workbook, talvez te ajude.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar varias sheet num único arquivo, e cada sheet pode conter as informações relacionada a cada arquivo.

```
Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();  // or new XSSFWorkbook();
Sheet sheet1 = wb.createSheet("new sheet");
Sheet sheet2 = wb.createSheet("second sheet");

// Note that sheet name is Excel must not exceed 31 characters
// and must not contain any of the any of the following characters:
// 0x0000
// 0x0003
// colon (:)
// backslash (\)
// asterisk (*)
// question mark (?)
// forward slash (/)
// opening square bracket ([)
// closing square bracket (])

// You can use org.apache.poi.ss.util.WorkbookUtil#createSafeSheetName(String nameProposal)}
// for a safe way to create valid names, this utility replaces invalid characters with a space (' ')
String safeName = WorkbookUtil.createSafeSheetName("[O'Brien's sales*?]"); // returns " O'Brien's sales   "
Sheet sheet3 = wb.createSheet(safeName);

FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("workbook.xls");
wb.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();
```

> https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#NewSheet